# UINavigationController how to set title

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a Controller/View for a generic list of items, that can be extended for displaying a custom list.. Listing and navigation works fine.. but I can't change the title of UINavigationController.
In the generic Controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addSubview: navigationController.view];
}
- (void)setNavigationTitle: (NSString *)title
{
    NSLog(@"set title: %@", title); // this works
    self.navigationController.title = title; // Nothing works here
}
```

Then, the extended class does..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setNavigationTitle: @"Custom list"];
}
```

The navigationBar still have "Item" as title :(

Comment: Did you solve this problem and can you tell me what should be done?

Comment: the "accepted" (by @willcodejavaforfood)response solved this for me.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In your `UIViewController` there is a `title` property and it is that property that will be displayed by the `NavigationController`. So when pushing a new `UIViewController` onto the navigation stack set the title of that `UIViewController` to whatever is appropriate.

In your case it looks like it would be:

```
[self setTitle:@"WhateverTitle"];
```

Comment: the first view is not pushed: [self.view addSubview: navigationController.view]; i tried also: self.title = @"AAAA"; [self.view addSubview: navigationController.view]; and does not works

Comment: In the pushed views (when user selects an item), the title is changed correctly

Comment: I notice that you didn't set a rootViewController for navigation controller. The first view controller in navigationController is called rootViewController. You may set its title using self.title = @"xxx".

Comment: my navigationbar does not have a "rootViewController" :?

Comment: self.title = @"Title"; is working

Answer (score 14):

For those looking for a Swift solution:

```
class CustomViewController: SuperViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "My Custom Title"
  }
}
```

The `title` needs to be set on the `UIViewController` and not on the `UINavigationController`embedding the view controller.

Documentation: [`UIViewController` Class Reference: `title` Property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/title)

Answer (score 5):

use

```
self.title = @"yourTitle";
```

Comment: I have now: NSLog(@"set title: %@", title); self.title = title; self.navigationItem.title = title; self.navigationController.title = title; // none of these works :/

Comment: set title in - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated method

Answer (score 4):

#### Swift

`title = "whateverTitle"`. It's a `UIViewController` instance property ; invoke anytime.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621364-title):

> **Declaration**
> `var title: String? { get set }`
>
> **Discussion**
> Set the title to a human-readable string that describes the view. If the view controller has a valid navigation item or tab-bar item, assigning a value to this property updates the title text of those objects.

Answer (score 0):

I know its old thread but thought of sharing this
Set the 'self.title' in 'init' method in UIVIewControler derived class,
This worked for me!!